# bashrc export TEXEDIT emacs

Tags: errors, compiling, emacs, bash

If PDFLaTeX fails to compile with

> See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation. Type  H
>     for immediate help.

I want to press `e` to get an instance of Emacs. The cursor should be on the position of the error (if TeX knows it)

I guess I should insert

```
export TEXEDIT="emacs magic"
```

to my `.bashrc` but what should I type instead of magic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since I have always an emacs open (with an emacs server active), I personally have this

```bash
export TEXEDIT="emacsclient --no-wait +%d %s"
```

which makes sure that you do not open tons of emacs windows around.  Otherwise, just use

```bash
export TEXEDIT="emacs +%d %s"
```

Both versions make emacs go to the right line.

It is important to have no space left and right of the = sign.

Answer (score 1):

Useful. You can somewhat "unify" the two solutions as emacsclient has a fallback editor in case the (emacs) server is not running:

export TEXEDIT="emacsclient --alternate-editor=emacs --no-wait +%d %s"